# Multiple development certificates for developer provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Is it possible to generate multiple development certificate for single provisioning profile without APNs/ In App purchase(Wildcard). If yes, please guide me. My problem is I need to generate provisioning profile and certificate for testing but already there is one development certificate in member centre I do not have the keys.

Comment: Did you try creating a certificate and then using Team Provisioning Profile? This is the most convenient way becasue you don't have to manually update all your provisioning profiles each time.

Comment: @lawicko Team Provisioning profile?? please explain.

Comment: [Team Provisioning Profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things

1) Revoke certificate from member center and generate new certificates and then create new provisional profile.

2) If you know that from which mac you have created that certificate(current certificate in member center) then you can export .p12 file from that mac and install it in current mac.